# Saving user data(which is in my class format) with sharedPrefrences or JSON

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I've just finished a course for learning Flutter last project was a simple Todo-List, it was really bothering that tasks can't be there after closing the app.
The full code as for course is [here](https://github.com/londonappbrewery/todoey-flutter)

My code which doesn't differ at all:

I really like the provider and Task class work so I didn't like to change it, so instead I tried to save data as what it is, by making two lists one for strings and another for booleans taking them out to save them (write), and then read and put them in their original place(Read)
Theoretically like that -- Task(StringList[index],boolList[index]) inside a loop -- as the respect of Task class; when i try to use SharedPreferences to save i made a dummy code that makes adding tasks doesn't work

any saving way will be helpful, my dummy thoughts or any thing.

'data' class where the sharedPreferences try:

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'tasks.dart';
class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier{


 List<Task> _tasks = [];

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks => UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);

  int get taskCount => _tasks.length;

  String _string;
  String _bool;

  void addTask(String newTaskName) async{
    final task = Task(name: newTaskName);
    _tasks.add(task);

// here is the code

    SharedPreferences sPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<SharedPreferences> sPrefs =[];
    SharedPreferences bPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<SharedPreferences> bPrefs =[];

    for(var item = 0; item <= taskCount; item++){
      //String Preferences
      sPref.setString(_string, tasks[item].name);
      sPrefs.add(sPref);

      //boolean Preferences
      bPref.setBool(_bool,tasks[item].isDone);
      bPrefs.add(bPref);
    }

// code is finished

    notifyListeners();
  }
  void updateTask(Task task){
    task.toggleIsDone();
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void removeTask(Task task){
    _tasks.remove(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }


}
```

tasks class (the way the data saved in tasks array)

```
class Task {
  final String name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({this.name, this.isDone = false});

  void toggleIsDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

now other classes that are involved but doesn't differ from github code

ADDing tasks:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:todoey_flutter/components/constants.dart';
import 'package:todoey_flutter/modules/task_data.dart';


class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String userTask;
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF737373),
      height: 600,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
        decoration: kContainerBoxRadius,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Add a Task',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  fontSize: 36,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade700),
                onChanged: (inputTask) {
                  userTask = inputTask;
                },
                autofocus: true,
                cursorRadius: Radius.circular(32.0),
                enableSuggestions: true,
                enabled: true,
                expands: false,
                controller: controller,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12.0,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (userTask == null) {}
                else {
                  controller.clear();
                  Provider.of<TaskData>(context).addTask(userTask);
                  print(TaskData().taskCount);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Text(
                  'ADD',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

task List:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:todoey_flutter/modules/task_data.dart';
import 'task_tile.dart';

class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final task = taskData.tasks[index];
            return TaskTile(
                text: task.name,
                isChecked: task.isDone,
                toggleCheckBoxState: (bool newValue) =>
                    taskData.updateTask(task),
                longPressIdentify: () => taskData.removeTask(task),
            );
          },
          itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

TaskTile is class with some constructors there is no use for Task class or data inside it

finally main subsidary class from main.dart>>(where the provider is) task screen:

```
//a lot of imports mainly task_data and task list and provider and adding tasks class

class TaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 42.0, right: 36.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 48.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(),
              );
            }),
      ),
      body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 50.0, top: 120.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 50.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.list,
                      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                      size: 60.0,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    radius: 40.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 36.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Todoey',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      fontSize: 55.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '${Provider.of<TaskData>(context).taskCount} Tasks',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: kContainerBoxRadius,
                child: TaskList(),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

sorry I didn't removed the layout codes so it makes blockes of code big
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can convert `List<Task>` to `JSON` string and directly save this `JSON` string 
When your APP `init()` , you can read this `JSON` string and convert back to `List<Task>` 
code snippet

```
 void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => TaskData()..init(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

 List<Task> taskFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Task>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Task.fromJson(x)));

 String taskToJson(List<Task> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
    
 void init() async {
    SharedPreferences sPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String jsonTask = sPref.getString("task");
    print(jsonTask);
    if (jsonTask != null) {
      _tasks = taskFromJson(jsonTask);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void saveToPreference() async {
    SharedPreferences sPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sPref.setString("task", taskToJson(_tasks));
  }

  void addTask(String newTaskName) async {
    final task = Task(name: newTaskName);
    _tasks.add(task);
    await saveToPreference();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isChecked;
  final String text;
  final Function toggleCheckBoxState;
  final Function longPressIdentify;

  TaskTile(
      {this.isChecked,
      this.text,
      this.toggleCheckBoxState,
      this.longPressIdentify});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onLongPress: longPressIdentify,
      title: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: toggleCheckBoxState,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final task = taskData.tasks[index];
            return TaskTile(
              text: task.name,
              isChecked: task.isDone,
              toggleCheckBoxState: (bool newValue) => taskData.updateTask(task),
              longPressIdentify: () => taskData.removeTask(task),
            );
          },
          itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class AddTaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddTaskScreenState createState() => _AddTaskScreenState();
}

class _AddTaskScreenState extends State<AddTaskScreen> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  String userTask;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF737373),
      height: 600,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
        //decoration: kContainerBoxRadius,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Add a Task',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  fontSize: 36,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade700),
                onChanged: (inputTask) {
                  userTask = inputTask;
                },
                //autofocus: true,
                cursorRadius: Radius.circular(32.0),
                enableSuggestions: true,
                enabled: true,
                expands: false,
                controller: controller,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12.0,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(controller.text);
                print("onpressed $userTask");
                if (userTask == null) {
                } else {
                  controller.clear();
                  Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false)
                      .addTask(userTask);
                  print(TaskData().taskCount);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Text(
                  'ADD',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Task> taskFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Task>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Task.fromJson(x)));

String taskToJson(List<Task> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Task {
  final String name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({this.name, this.isDone = false});

  void toggleIsDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }

  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Task(
        name: json["name"],
        isDone: json["isDone"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "isDone": isDone,
      };
}

class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Task> _tasks = [];

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks => UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);

  int get taskCount => _tasks.length;

  String _string;
  String _bool;

  void init() async {
    SharedPreferences sPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String jsonTask = sPref.getString("task");
    print(jsonTask);
    if (jsonTask != null) {
      _tasks = taskFromJson(jsonTask);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void saveToPreference() async {
    SharedPreferences sPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sPref.setString("task", taskToJson(_tasks));
  }

  void addTask(String newTaskName) async {
    final task = Task(name: newTaskName);
    _tasks.add(task);
    await saveToPreference();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateTask(Task task) async {
    task.toggleIsDone();
    await saveToPreference();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeTask(Task task) async {
    _tasks.remove(task);
    await saveToPreference();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class TaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 42.0, right: 36.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 48.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(),
              );
            }),
      ),
      body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 50.0, top: 120.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 50.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.list,
                      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                      size: 60.0,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    radius: 40.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 36.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Todoey',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      fontSize: 55.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '${Provider.of<TaskData>(context).taskCount} Tasks',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                //decoration: kContainerBoxRadius,
                child: TaskList(),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => TaskData()..init(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: TaskScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```